# Importing multiple .csv files into R and adding a new column with file name

Tags: r, csv

I have 80 separate .csv files that have the same columns and headers that I was able to import and rbind as one dataframe using the following commands:

```
 file_names <- dir("~/Desktop/data") 
 df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(file_names,read.csv))
```

But I would like to add a new variable ("name") that identifies from which .csv file each observation came from. So for example, this variable "name" would be "NY" for all the observations from the 'NY.csv' file and "DC" for all observations from the 'DC.csv' file, etc...
Is there any way to do this without adding this new column manually on each .csv? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
file_names <- dir("~/Desktop/data") 
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(file_names, function(x) cbind(read.csv(x), name=strsplit(x,'\\.')[[1]][1])))
```

Comment: Hey @mpjdem I like where you are going with this, but I get the following error. Any idea why/how to solve it?  Thanks! "Error in !header : invalid argument type"

Comment: Does it help explicitly set `header=TRUE` in the `read.csv()` call? (supposing you do have a header; otherwise `header=FALSE`)

Comment: No, I still get the same error. I have a header; can't figure it out.  @mpjdem

Answer (score 2):

With `readr >= 2.0` just add the `id` option:

```
library(readr)
read_csv(file_names, id = "name")
```

If you would like to remove the `csv` at the end:

```
read_csv(file_names, id = "name") %>%
   mutate(name = str_remove_all(name, ".csv"))
```

See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46299777/add-filename-column-to-table-as-multiple-files-are-read-and-bound) for more options.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `idcol` argument from `data.table`'s `rbindlist()` function:

```
# get a vector of all file names
myfiles <- list.files("path/to/directory/")

# loop over files names, reading in and saving each data.frame as an element in a list
n <- length(myfiles )
datalist <- vector(mode="list", length=n)
for(i in 1:n) {
    cat("importing file", i, ":", myfiles[i], "\n")
    datalist[[i]] <- read.csv(myfiles[i])
}

# assign list elements the file names
names(datalist) <- myfiles 

# combine all data.frames in datalist, use idcol argument to assign original file name
all_data <- data.table::rbindlist(datalist, idcol=TRUE)
```