# Insert a column with file name

Tags: r

Having this code it is possible to read multiple csv from a file path

```
setwd("C:/Users/Nathalie/mycsvs")
files <- list.files(path = "C:/Users/Nathalie/mycsvs",pattern = ".csv")
temp <- lapply(files, fread, sep=",")
```

How is it possible to add a column to the dataframe which will have the file name each row came from?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add "filename" column to table as multiple files are read and bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46299777/add-filename-column-to-table-as-multiple-files-are-read-and-bound)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `Map` and create a new column with `cbind` to show filename for each file.

```
Map(cbind, lapply(files, data.table::fread, sep=","), filename = files)
```

We can also use functions from `purrr` package to do the same.

```
library(purrr)
map2(map(files, data.table::fread, sep=","), files, cbind)
```

---

To use `lapply`, we can loop over the index of filenames instead and use `transform` to add new column with name of the file.

```
lapply(seq_along(files), function(x) transform(read.csv(files[x]), file = files[x]))
```