# Assign 'filename' column to dataframe based on row ID

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have constructed a data frame by row binding different web-scraped tables.

```
# html files
filelist <- c("Prod223_2688_00185641_20190930.html","Prod224_0078_SO305092_20191130.html", 
"Prod224_0078_SO305426_20190831.html", "Prod224_0078_SO305431_20190831.html", 
"Prod224_0078_SO305440_20190831.html", "Prod224_0078_SO305451_20200331.html", 
"Prod224_0078_SO306088_20190531.html", "Prod224_0078_SO306098_20180630.html", 
"Prod224_0078_SO306098_20190630.html", "Prod224_0078_SO306411_20190530.html")

# web scraping tables
mydata <- lapply(filelist, function(x) {
  read_html(x) %>% rvest::html_table(fill = T) %>% 
    dplyr::nth(2) 
})

# row binding (adding a new column with row .id)
mydata <- rbindlist(mydata, idcol=T, fill = T)
```

I want to create a new column `company` with the respective name from `filelist` based on row .id. The company name is the third code in between `_`.  To get something like this:

```
mydata
 company  id.  X2 ..
00185641    1  .. 
00185641    1  .. 
SO305092    2  .. 
SO305426    3  .. 
SO305426    3  ..
```

This may be quite a simple question but I am not confident with functions in R yet. I have seen this similar [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46299777/add-filename-column-to-table-as-multiple-files-are-read-and-bound) and tried:

```
mydata2 <- mydata2 %>% mutate(company=lapply(mydata2,filelist))
# and this:
mydata2$company <- rep(paste(filelist), length(mydata2$.id))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't have data to test this on but you can try the following :

```
library(dplyr)
library(rvest)

mydata <- sapply(filelist, function(x) {
  read_html(x) %>% rvest::html_table(fill = TRUE) %>% 
    dplyr::nth(2) 
}, simplify = FALSE)

mydata <- bind_rows(mydata, .id = ='company')
mydata$company <- sub('.*_(\\w+)_\\w+', '\\1', mydata$company)
```

We used `sapply` with `simplify = FALSE` to get a named list with `filelist` as names, when we use `bind_rows` that name is assigned as a new column `company`. Using regex we extract the relevant part of the data.